# How to exclude something from forEach on discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am programming in discord.js and I am making a command which would kick everybody from a server. The thing is, I wanted to kick everyone except me, and I don't know how to do that, nor did I find any tutorial on it. Here is my code:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gone`)) {
      message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => member.ban())
    }
      
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const MY_USER_ID = 'your user id'
bot.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}gone`)) {
    message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id !== MY_USER_ID) {
        member.ban()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make sure to use and test it

Answer (score 1):

In your `.forEach()` loop you need to add a check to see if the `member` has the same ID as you so you could do this two ways:

Either by making the bot ignore the user who typed in the command:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id !== message.author.id) member.ban()
})
```

Or if you want to just make it not ban you specifically then:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  if (member.id !== 'USER_ID') member.ban()
})
```

You can also write those checks inside of a `.filter()` like so:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.id !== 'USER_ID').forEach(member => member.ban())
```

Comment: Alternatively `.filter().forEach()` would also be an option.